# How can i do a dynamic subdomain redirect

Tags: c#, .net, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

How can i redirect a shortcode subdomain to a different site with /shortcode.  Here is the kicker, i have thousands of short codes like "xpdf", "ddsd", etc. so i cannot simply create the subdomain xpdf and put a redirect on it in IIS.  Is there a dynamic way to do this?

Comment: I had to do the same thing but based on sub domain and then based on folder. I used a custom httphandler as @DustinDavis suggested. Worked great. the url rewrite isapi didn't quite allow us the flexibility we needed but it's still a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the site host header to blank so it accepts all domains then either use iis rewriter isapi filter to do the redirect http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite or build a httphandler to do it checking the incoming host via httpcontext then redirect as needed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

also have a look at IIS redirect settings Site > Http Redirect